# Multibinding using Window's DataContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dependency-properties, datacontext

I'm trying to create drag adorner based on whether the `Customer` DependancyProperty of a Window is null. I have this in the Window's resources. The first part of the binding is set (the item being dragged), but the second (the DependancyProperty on the WIndow) shows as UnsetValue.

The property is definitely initialized as it's used as the window's datacontext.

```
<Window x:Name="root"
    ...
>
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DragAdorner">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource vehicleDragConverter}">
                        <Binding/>
                        <Binding Path="Customer" ElementName="root"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

customer is not a direct property of element window.

1. use `<Binding Path="DataContext.Customer"..../>`

or you can also use RelativeSource=FindControl Window in binding.

Comment: RelativeSource doesn't work, and I still get unset value when using `DataContext.Customer`: 
`Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=root'...`

Comment: use AncestorType in RelativeResource

Comment: you have set the DataContext = this in code? because it should work.